# Guessing which side of N coins are up

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume there are N coins, each with a unique ID. These coin are tossed and your task is to guess which side is up for each coin. You are allowed to submit your guesses to a server, and it will tell you how many you got correct. You are only allowed to use the server M times. In the case of $N \rightarrow \infty$, What is the strategy that maximize the expected number of correct guesses?

One strategy would be firstly guess all coins are H, submit to the server, if got more than 50% correct, keep it, otherwise change all to T. Then flip the first half of the guesses, submit to the server, if number of correct guessese increase, keep it, otherwise flip the guesses back, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy is to split the coins into $M$ groups of (roughly) equal size. Denote these groups $G_{1}, G_{2}, \dots G_{M}$. Your initial guess would be $d_{0}$ with all coins in all groups being set to $0$. Denote $c_{0}$ to be the number of correct coins in this guess.  This will be followed by $M-1$ guesses $d_1, d_2,\dots d_{M-1}$ where the guess $d_{k}$ would be that all coins are $0$, except  those in group $G_{k}$, which are set to $1$.

Let $c_{1}, c_{2}\dots c_{M-1}$ be the number of correct coins in these guesses. From these and arithmetic we can deduce the number of correct coins in $c_{M}$ in guess $d_{M}$, without actually having to make that guess. We have: $$c_{M} = (M-1)c_{0} + N -\sum_{k=1}^{M-1} c_{k} $$

Now having made those guesses, our final solution would be the sequence $d_{S}$, defined by: for $k\in\{1\dots M\}$ the coins in group $G_{k}$ will be set to $0$ if $c_{0} > c_{k}$, or $1$ otherwise.  This solution will be guaranteed to have for every group $G_{k}$ at least half the coins in it guessed correctly. The number of correct guesses will be:

$$c = c_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^{M} \max(0,c_{k}-c_{0})$$

Now we will calculate the expected value of the number of correct guesses. Start with $N$ coins and a single guess, with the strategy being to guess for all coins $0$ and choose all $1$'s if $c_0 < \frac{N}{2}$ (as described in the initial post). Summing over all possibilities, the expected value is:
$$E[c] = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{N}{{N}\choose{k}}\max(k,n-k)}{2^{N}}$$

The expression $a(N) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}{{N}\choose{k}}\max(k,n-k)$ is described by [OEIS:A230137](https://oeis.org/A230137) and has the formula:
$$a(2n) = (4^n + {{2n}\choose{n}})n\\
a(2n+1) = (4^n + {{2n}\choose{n}})(2n+1)$$
We will restrict ourselves to even $N$ for convenience. This gives the expected value for a single guess of:

$$E[c]= \frac{a(N)}{2^N} = \frac{(2^{N} + {{N}\choose{N/2}})\frac{N}{2} }{2^{N}} =  \frac{N}{2} ( 1 +  {{{N}\choose{N/2}}}/{2^{N}}) $$

The quantity ${{{N}\choose{N/2}}}/{2^{N}}$ starts as $0.5$ for $N=2$ and shrinks off rapidly as $N$ increases:

[image]

What this means is that $\frac{E[c]}{N}$ is larger for smaller $N$ (with a lower bound of $\frac{1}{2}$). Now applying our above strategy for $M$ guesses over $N$ coins, the expected value will be (approximately) $M$ times the expected value of $1$ guess over $N/M$ coins (as we've split the coins into $M$ groups of roughly $N/M$ coins each). This gives:

$$E[c] = \frac{N}{2} ( 1 +  {{{N/M}\choose{N/2M}}}/{2^{\frac{N}{M}}})  $$